# SQL root password lost on XtradbCluster Percona, how to reset?

Tags: mysql, change-password, forgot-password, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have a big problem.
I have crash my PC, so I lost the ROOT password to access a Perconna Xtradbcluster Databases.

I have access on the Centos ROOT user on clusters servers. (so not too bad)
How can i change or reset the password without crashing all databases ?

Information:

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41-37.0, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

# service mysql status
SUCCESS! MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) running (7092)
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the common ways to reset the root password?

Comment: Hello @Nicohaase,

No i did not tried, it is a production environnement.
And it is a Percona Cluster. So maybe it is more specific ... i prefer ask before broke everything.

Comment: If some one can help :-)

Comment: I found this tutorial : 
https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

But it is a cluster, does i need to stop mysql instances on the other servers before proceed ?

Sound logical, but sometimes logical it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to follow that tutorial just fine on only 1 of the PXC nodes. When you issue the 'UPDATE' to change the password, it should replicate immediately to the other nodes. Be sure to restart this node with skip-grant-tables turned OFF after you change the password.